# What happened to the Detapa council after Dukat's coup?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the DS9 episode *Way of the Warrior* *part 1*, Gul Dukat "saw which way the wind was blowing" and sided with the civilian uprising against Central Command; as a result he answered to the new government called the Detapa Council.

Later in season five's *By Inferno's Light*, Dukat has seized control of Cardassia with the help of the Dominion.

So what was the fate of the civilian government after this development? Were they imprisoned? Executed?

Comment: I would imagine they were all murdered. Let's find out, shall we?

Comment: Yup. All murdered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the EU novel [*The Never-Ending Sacrifice*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Never-Ending_Sacrifice), the Detapa Council was, by and large, executed. One of their number survived (briefly) but was killed in the genocide committed by the Dominion against Cardassia Prime at the end of the Dominion War.

> A third before the first bell, when it was still dark, the [council] building was stormed by the Jem’Hadar. They marched in, seized the Chief Executor and the Chief Archon, dragged them out and executed them on the spot. The images played on every channel for weeks afterward, in between repeat showings of Gul Dukat’s accession speech.
>
> ...
>
> A civilian militia was created—a fifth of the strength of the previous
> police force and directly answerable to Dukat—but the Jem’Hadar took
> over maintenance of law and order in all urban centers. **The rest of
> the Detapa Council was tried and executed for “weakening the
> Cardassian state.”** Some high-ranking Assembly members shared this
> fate; others were interned in labor camps or placed under house
> arrest. As for the rest of the Five: **Erek Rhemet, who had been
> offworld at the time, was rumored to have sought asylum in Mathenite
> space, joining Tekeny Ghemor to form a government-in-exile.**